# What would be an example of a magma such that $x\cdot(x\cdot x)\neq (x\cdot x)\cdot x$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Let $(M,\cdot)$ be a non-associative magma.

What would be an example of $M$ such that there exists $x\in M$ such that $x\cdot(x\cdot x)\neq (x\cdot x)\cdot x$?

Comment: Free magmas are good for counterexamples of equalities.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The set of positive real numbers $\mathbb{R}^+$ with the operation of division $/$ is an example. Here $x/(x/x)=x \neq 1/x =(x/x)/x$ if $x \neq 1$.

Another example is the operation $(x,y) \mapsto x^y$ on $\mathbb{N}$. It is a coincidence that we have $x^{(x^x)} = (x^x)^x$ for $x \in \{1,2\}$, but we have $0^{(0^0)} \neq (0^0)^0$ and $3^{(3^3)} \neq (3^3)^3$

The free magma on one generator $x$ is another example (and this *must* be an example if there is any example, because of the universal property). The free magma on one generator is the set of finite binary trees with the operation "joining along a new root". Here are the two binary trees representing $x*(x*x) \neq (x*x)*x$:

```
   /\     /\
    /\   /\
```

Comment: The answer by Aaron Meyerowitz shows that the operation "division" works for arbitrary groups.

Answer (score 7):

A magma is just a set $S$  with a binary operation $S\times S:\rightarrow S$ .

In the integers with ordinary subtraction , $(\mathbb{Z},-).$ The equations $$x-(x-x)=(x-x)-x$$ almost never holds, in fact it only holds for $x=0.$

More generally, pick a group $G$ and define $a \star b=ab^{-1}$ then $$x \star (x \star x)=x$$ $$(x \star x) \star x=x^{-1}$$
These are not just magmas, they are quasigroups.

As far as commutative but non-associative magmas: In a commutative magma one would have $(x \cdot x) \cdot x=x \cdot(x \cdot x).$ However given an abelian group $(G,+)$ we can define $a \cdot b=2(a+b)=a+a+b+b .$ This is commutative  but usually $$(a\cdot b)\cdot c=4a+4b+2c <>2a+4b+4c=a\cdot(b \cdot c).$$ If all the elements of $G$ have odd order, then this is again a quasi-group.

Answer (score 3):

This one.
$$
\begin{align}
1 \cdot 1 & = 2 \\
1 \cdot 2 & = 1 \\
2 \cdot 1 & = 2 \\
2 \cdot 2 & = 1
\end{align}
$$

$1 \cdot (1\cdot 1) = 1$ and $(1\cdot 1)\cdot 1=2$

What would be an example of non-associative but commutative magma ?

Comment: No this one is not the one I'm looking for. See that $1\cdot (1\cdot 1)=(1\cdot 1)\cdot 1$. Even $2\cdot (2\cdot 2)=(2\cdot 2)\cdot 2$.

Comment: Change it so $1\cdot 1=2$ and $2\cdot 2=1$

Comment: Should I ? If I change it, Rubertos' comment does not make sense anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one:

Pick fixed, distinct elements $x,v,w,z$ in $M$, and define $\cdot$ by

$$a\cdot b= \begin{cases} z & \text{if $a=b=x$} \\ x & \text{ if $a\neq x$ and $b\neq x$} \\ v & \text{ if $a=x$ and $b\neq x$} \\ w & \text{ if $a\neq x$ and $b=x$} \end{cases}$$

Then we would find that $x\cdot (x\cdot x)=x\cdot z=v$ but $(x\cdot x)\cdot x=z\cdot x=w$.
This works so long as $|M|\geq 4$.

Answer (score 1):

As @davcha pointed out already, it is easy to work out an example among finite magmas. Look at the Cayley table:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\cdot & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 0
\end{array}$$

over the set $M=\{0,1,2,3\}$. Here we have

$$(1\cdot 1)\cdot 1=0\cdot1=0\ne 1=1\cdot 0=1\cdot(1\cdot 1),$$

and so on with $x=2$ and $x=3$.

Answer (score 0):

The set of truth-values $M=\{\mathbf T,\mathbf F\}$ with the operation $\to$; that is, $\mathbf T\to\mathbf F=\mathbf F$ and $\mathbf T\to\mathbf T=\mathbf F\to\mathbf T=\mathbf F\to\mathbf F=\mathbf T$. Then
$$\mathbf F\to(\mathbf F\to\mathbf F)=\mathbf F\to\mathbf T=\mathbf T$$
while
$$(\mathbf F\to\mathbf F)\to\mathbf F=\mathbf T\to\mathbf F=\mathbf F.$$